# Trying to read data from a file and turn each line into a list, but it skips some values

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make a simple text-based game and I need to store player's scores. So, I made this little script that would get the data from a file, and (supposedly) do this:

- Loop through each word, and add that word to a list of its line;
- When the program hits a new line, add the line list to a general list, which would contain everything.

This is my code:

```
def readData(path):
    file = open(path, 'r')
    data = []
    curWord = ''
    curLineData = []

    while True:
        char = file.read(1)
        if not char == '\n':
            if not char == ' ':
                curWord = curWord.join(char)
            else:
                curLineData.append(curWord)
                curWord = ''
        else:
            data.append(curLineData)
            curLineData = []
            curWord = ''

        if not char:
            break

    file.close()
    return data
```

These are the contents of file.txt:

```
p1 1 4
p2 2 18
p3 3 3
```

Here is my problem: Whenever I run the code, I get this:

```
[['1', '1'], ['2', '2'], ['3', '3']]
```

When I expected to get:

```
[['p1', '1', '4'], ['p2', '2', '18'], ['p3', '3', '3']]
```

The problem is that it will skip the first word, add the second one and then repeat the first word for as many words as it finds. After some testing, I also found out that it will only add the last line if there is an empty line at the end.

I would love to know what I am doing wrong (besides being stupid) and it would be great if you could tell me how to fix it :)

Comment: Generally it is more pythonic to do `for line in file:...` if you can. Each iteration will give the next line of the file.

Comment: Please write down the desired output as well

Comment: @ari OK. I will try to do that and share the results.

Comment: @user1767754 the desired output is [['p1', '1', '4'], ['p2', '2', '18'], ['p3', '3', '3']]. I will update the question

Answer (score 2):

`str.join` does not append a string to the end of the one invoking the method; it uses the invoker as a "separator" to join together each element of the argument to `join`. That is, you seem to think that `"foo".join("bar")` would produce `"foobar"`, when it actually would produce `"bfooafoor"`.

A much better approach is to simply read the file line-by-line, and split each line into words using whitespace as the separator:

```
def readData(path):
    rv = []
    with open(path, 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            words = line.split()
            rv.append(words)
    return rv
```

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe how I managed to make such a mess for such a simple thing :D I definitely should have though about `str.split()`. Also, thanks for pointing out what the `str.join` method does. I didn't know about that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
def readData(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as myfile:
        lines = myfile.readlines()
    return [line.strip().split(' ') for line in lines]
```

A few differences between your code and this one:

- When handling a file, it is often best to use a `with` statement (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html)
- it is best not to use the name `file` for a variable as it is a built-in type
- you can use the `readlines` method which returns a list of lines
- you can use the `split` method to split each line into a list
- you can use a list comprehension to build your final list

Comment: The only reason why I am using chepner's answer instead of this one is because this one will leave the `\n` in the output. Besides that, thanks!

Comment: As far as using a built-in name as a variable, `file` is one of the less likely to cause a problem. Unlike a type like `str` or `dict`, there is another function (`open`) that is preferred for creating instances of `file`.

Comment: @pta2002 no problem :-) ... I edited my answer to remove the new line in the output (i used `strip` before splitting).

Comment: @chepner that is true, but i don't think it is a good practice anyway